# How to sort column with dates on md-data-table using md-order-by attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatable, angular-material

I'm trying to allow ordering a column of a [md-data-table](https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table#column-sorting) in AngularJS that contains dates. These dates are strings with the format DD / MM / YYYY. I can not get them ordered correctly. I have tried to call a function that returns the timestamp of the date from the md-order-by attribute, but it does not even call the function. The current code is the following and the column that I am trying to order is Fecha Nacimiento:

```
 <table md-table md-row-select="options.rowSelection" multiple="{{options.multiSelect}}" ng-model="selected"
         md-progress="promise">
    <thead md-head md-order="query.order">
    <tr md-row>
      <th md-column md-order-by="id"><span>Identificador</span></th>
      <th md-column md-numeric md-order-by="fechaTimestamp(fechaNacimiento)"><span>Fecha Nacimiento</span></th>
      <th md-column md-order-by="sexo"><span>Sexo</span></th>
      <th md-column md-numeric md-order-by="altura"><span>Altura(cm)</span></th>
      <th md-column><span>Grabaciones</span></th>
      <th md-column><span>Atributos extra</span></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody md-body>
    <tr md-row md-select="paciente" md-on-select="logItem" md-auto-select="options.autoSelect"
        ng-repeat="paciente in pacientes.data | filter: filter.search | orderBy: query.order | limitTo: query.limit : (query.page -1) * query.limit">
      <td md-cell ng-click="editarCampo($event, paciente, 'identificador')"
          ng-class="{'md-placeholder': !paciente.id}">{{paciente.id || 'Añadir identificador'}}
      </td>
      <td md-cell ng-click="editarFecha($event, paciente)" ng-class="{'md-placeholder': !paciente.fechaNacimiento}">
        {{paciente.fechaNacimiento
        || "Añadir fecha nacimiento"}}
      </td>
      <td md-cell>
        <md-select ng-model="paciente.sexo" name="sexo" ng-change="editarSexo(paciente)" placeholder="Sexo" required>
          <md-option value="Hombre">Hombre</md-option>
          <md-option value="Mujer">Mujer</md-option>
          <md-option value="Otro">Otro</md-option>
        </md-select>
      </td>
      <td md-cell ng-click="editarCampo($event, paciente, 'altura')"
          ng-class="{'md-placeholder': !paciente.altura}">{{paciente.altura || 'Añadir altura'}}
      </td>
      <td md-cell>
        <md-button ng-click="redirect('grabaciones/' + paciente.id)"
                   style="background: lightgrey;" ng-show="paciente.grabaciones"
                   title="Ver grabaciones de {{paciente.id}}">Ver
        </md-button>
      </td>
      <td md-cell>
        <md-button ng-click="verAtributosExtra($event,paciente)" ng-show="paciente.extra"
                   style="background: lightgrey;"
                   title="Ver información extra de {{paciente.id}}">Ver
        </md-button>
        <md-button ng-click="verAtributosExtra($event,paciente)" ng-hide="paciente.extra"
                   style="background: lightgrey;"
                   title="Añadir atributos extra a {{paciente.id}}">Añadir
        </md-button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling function on `md-order-by` doesn't work. So what you'll have to do, is changing date property of `pacients.data` objects. You saying you receiving it in the form of DD/MM/YYYY string right? So just manipulate pacients.data array & change date property to object with its own properties as value & ts (timestamp) in the view you can bind the `date.vale` & in `md-order-by` you can bind `date.ts`.

For manipulation I've created one example with function as:

```
$scope.addDateTimestamps = function() {
    var arrData = $scope.pacientes.data;
    var newData = arrData.map(function(item,index) {
        var dateString = item.date;
        var dateParts = dateString.split("/");
        var dateObject = new Date(dateParts[2], dateParts[1] - 1, dateParts[0]);
        item.date = {'value': dateString, 'ts': dateObject.getTime()};
        return item;
    });
    $scope.pacientes.data = newData;
}
```

So this function will convert DD/MM/YYYY date to dateobject & then getting timestamp. Call this function when you get data from service & you create model.
You can follow below codepen where I've added date field with string values bind & sorting based on timestamp.

Alternatively you can even just change date property from array objects string to timestamp & then on view you can use date filter to show it in different formats & in md-order-by just date (ts) property

**[Codepen Eample](https://codepen.io/shantanu_kulkarrni/pen/bMzeda)**

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you very much for your response